# How to run a secondary query within a primary query inside a for each loop

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

How can I modify my code to allow me to run a second query in the for each loop?

For now I have commented out the second query, as Im sure I need to make some changes prior to removing the slashes.

```
    <?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('LOGIN DETAILS HERE');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM toptips WHERE userid = 2"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
{ $rows[] = $row; }

foreach($rows as $row) { 

    $id = $row['id'];
    echo $row['time'] . " " . $row['course'] . " - " . $row['horse'] . " " . $row['description'] ."<br/>"; 

        // second query here
    // $query2 = "SELECT likes FROM Likes_table WHERE id = $id";
    // $result = $mysqli->query($query2);
    // while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    // echo $row['likes'] . '<br />';
    // }

}

?>
```

Comment: uncomment your code and it looks fine to me

Answer (score 1):

Better use INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    toptips.*,
    Likes_table.likes
FROM 
    toptips 
INNER JOIN
    Likes_table
ON
    Likes_table.id=toptips.id
WHERE
    toptips.userid = 2
```

This will save you a lot of resources by removing the inner loop.

Comment: Ya, totally agree. It looks like you've got all the information required at the time you execute the first query to also retrieve the dataset that would be returned by the second query.

By executing the second query for every record returned by the first query, you've created an ["n+1" problem](http://www.pbell.com/index.cfm/2006/9/17/Understanding-the-n1-query-problem). Typically this won't cause any immediately apparent performance problems but the solution is such an easy optimization that it just makes sense to use it.